# What is the c parameter in an URL?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm seeing URL parameter with c=5 or c=3 in Google Analytics. I know that "s" stands for search, but I can't seem to find information on the "c" parameter.

Example URLs

- www.example.com/?c=5
- www.example.com/?c=3

Does anyone know?

Comment: Post an example of the URL, pls

Comment: The URL looks like this: www.example.com/?c=5. There are no other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know how website works, c should be the category, but no one can give you a certain answer, it depends on the site, the parameters are not absolute for all sites.